# how to set the datepicker input field with a value of string type

Tags: angularjs, angular-kendo

I need to set the kendo angular datepicker input field to a date value with a particular date format when my angular model is holding a string date value like "2014-08-21T11:27:04". can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *date* filter to change the model with defined date/time format in JavaScript or in HTML templates.

There is a lot of elements which can be used to compose a date string, so visit [**the official docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), where everything is well described.